# Using _.Omit To Delete Items In Array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Trying to use Underscore.js and having some issues with _.omit. Any help getting it to work would be appreciated.

I have a nested JSON array and I want to remove the "envelopeId" before displaying the data. Below is what I have so far.

```
var orders = {
    "nextUri": "", 
    "endPosition": "4", 
    "startPosition": "0", 
    "resultSetSize": "5", 
    "envelopes": [
      {
        "status": "completed", 
        "envelopeId": "8c2c0342-50e9-483e-8196-51060391e439", 
      }, 
      {
        "status": "completed", 
        "envelopeId": "b0d2db56-38ea-4435-b0ff-f90739823692", 
      }
    ], 
    "previousUri": "", 
    "totalSetSize": "5"
  };

_.each(orders, function(order) {     
   var newOrder = _.omit(orders.envelopes, 'envelopeId');
  });
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `newOrder`?

Comment: I'm just logging it for now. Forgot to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind that the `orders` object is modified, you can do it like this:

```
orders.envelopes = _.map(orders.envelopes, function (e) {
  return _.omit(e, "envelopeId");
});
```

This code will replace `orders.envelopes` with new array which `envelopId` is omitted.